# How to get polygon coordinates for Google Map from .poly files (preferably in nodejs)?

Tags: polygon, google-maps, google-maps-api

I have `.poly` files with polygons of countries. I want to use those polygons to make Google Map polygon layers. How may I read `lng` and `lat` points of polygons from those poly files? They look like these:

```
australia_v

1
     0.1446763E+03    -0.3825659E+02
     0.1446693E+03    -0.3826255E+02
     0.1446627E+03    -0.3825661E+02
     0.1446763E+03    -0.3824465E+02
     0.1446813E+03    -0.3824343E+02
     0.1446824E+03    -0.3824484E+02
     0.1446826E+03    -0.3825356E+02
     0.1446876E+03    -0.3825210E+02
     0.1446919E+03    -0.3824719E+02
     0.1447006E+03    -0.3824723E+02
     0.1447042E+03    -0.3825078E+02
     0.1446758E+03    -0.3826229E+02
     0.1446693E+03    -0.3826255E+02
END
!2
     0.1422483E+03    -0.3839481E+02
     0.1422436E+03    -0.3839315E+02
     0.1422496E+03    -0.3839070E+02
     0.1422543E+03    -0.3839025E+02
     0.1422574E+03    -0.3839155E+02
     0.1422467E+03    -0.3840065E+02
     0.1422433E+03    -0.3840048E+02
     0.1422420E+03    -0.3839857E+02
     0.1422436E+03    -0.3839315E+02
END
END
```

Which software or nodejs module may I use to read `.poly` files to get usual `lat`, `lng` coordinates?

Comment: you need to know the projection, do you know where is this? I mean in WGS84, (aka WGS 1984, EPSG:4326), use the share function from google maps to know the coordinates (they are in WGS84).

Comment: Hey can you tell me where did you get those polygon files?